# How to make Vite compile svgs as static files

Tags: reactjs, vite, storybook

Is it possible to make vite compile svgs as static files like webpacks file-loader plugin.

Attempting to override with `vite-svg-loader` or `vite-plugin-react-svg` seems not to work when setting the config to be `defaultExport: url` in the vite.config.js file.

vite.config.js file

```
export default defineConfig({
plugins: [reactRefresh(), reactSvgPlugin({defaultExport: 'url'})],
server: {
    fs: {
        allow: ['/'],
    },
},
```

});

Also tried

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import svgLoader from 'vite-svg-loader'
    
    export default defineConfig({
        plugins: [
            svgLoader({
                defaultImport: 'url',
            }),
        ],
        server: {
            fs: {
                allow: ['/'],
            },
        },
    });
```